# Accessibilty friendly with Primefaces

Tags: primefaces, wai-aria, nvda

I'm improving a website to be accessibility friendly. Having problems with the p:selectOneMenu: it's not reading the values in the drop down, it only read them as a 'Blank'. I understand primefaces renders it different than a normal selectMenu just not sure how. How can i fix this to read the drop down items?

Using : Primefaces 5.1 , Reader NVDA ,Firefox v42.0 (but should work with Chrome and Internet Explorer)

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="title" value="#{person.title}" required="true" styleClass="select"><f:selectItem itemLabel="#{bundle['please_select']}" itemValue="" />
  <f:selectItems value="#{utilsController.getCodeList('TITL', user, localeManager.getLanguage())}" />
  <p:ajax event="change" update="gender" listener="#{memberWizardController.autopopulateGender()}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

[image: Drop down]

Would appreciate if answer could explain how the p:selectOneMenu renders in html / DOM

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If accessibility is really important, this is just the first issue you encounter in PF 5.1. Use PrimeFaces 5.3.x or latest snapshot... Soooooo many improvements in this 'aria' (pun intended).

Comment: @Kukeltje Still have same problem. Upgraded to 5.3 and the document shows the same as the one from 5.1 for p:selectOneMenu

Comment: Also checked the releasenotes of newer one and commits in github? And how it renders html can easily be seen in the source of the component